# Error in attempting the combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> In how many ways can $15$ identical blankets be distributed among $6$
>   beggars such that everyone gets at least one blanket and two
>   particular beggars get equal blankets and another three particular
>   beggars get equal blankets.

**Attempt:**

First, $6$ blankets are given and then $9$ blankets are left. 
After that, according to me there are only two possibilities:

- Possibility $1$:

First set of *particular* beggars receives: $(3,3)$

Second set of *particular* beggars receives: $(1,1,1)$

- Possibility $2$:

First set of *particular* beggars receives: $(0,0)$

Second set of  *particular* beggars receives: $(3,3,3)$

However answer given is $12$.

Please tell me my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(0,0),(3,3,3),(0)$

$(0,0),(2,2,2),(3)$

$(0,0),(1,1,1),(6)$

$(0,0),(0,0,0),(9)$

$(1,1),(2,2,2),(1)$

$(1,1),(1,1,1),(4)$

$(1,1),(0,0,0),(7)$

$(2,2),(0,0,0),(5)$

$(2,2),(1,1,1),(2)$

$(3,3),(0,0,0),(3)$

$(3,3),(1,1,1),(0)$

$(4,4),(0,0,0),(1)$

Comment: Okay, so my mistake was that I assumed all the 9 remaining have to be given only to the two sets. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

For set of 2 and 3 beggars of equal number, and remaining one:

1-$(0,0),(0,0,0),(9)$
2-$(0,0),(1,1,1),(6)$
3-$(0,0),(2,2,2),(3)$
4-$(0,0),(3,3,3),(0)$
5-$(1,1),(0,0,0),(7)$
6-$(1,1),(2,2,2),(1)$
7-$(1,1),(1,1,1),(4)$
8-$(2,2),(0,0,0),(5)$
9-$(2,2),(1,1,1),(2)$
10-$(3,3),(0,0,0),(3)$
11-$(3,3),(1,1,1),(0)$
12-$(4,4),(0,0,0),(1)$

Comment: that's 8. Answer given is 12.

Comment: @Abcd edited...i too got 12...

Answer (score -2):

$a+ 2b + 3c = 15, a\ge 1, b\ge 1, c\ge 1$

$(10,1,1)\\
(8,2,1)\\
(7,1,2)\\
(6,3,1)\\
(5,2,2)\\
(4,1,3)\\
(4,4,1)\\
(3,3,2)\\
(2,2,3)\\
(1,1,4)\\
(2,5,1)\\
(1,4,2)$